# Randomly select 10 words from a text file

Tags: java, arrays, string, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

I am attempting to create a program that reads two text files, which both contain thousands of words. I need to be able to select 10 words at random from each file and store them in an array of four string lists. I have created the following code so far, however this only selects one word from each file, not 10. How can this be done - preferably using an if statement?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandomWordGenerator {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

public class RandomWordGenerator {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path outputFile = Paths.get("output.txt");
    ArrayList<String> randomWords1 = randomWordsFromFile("textfile1.txt", 10);
    ArrayList<String> randomWords2 = randomWordsFromFile("textfile2.txt", 10);
    OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(outputFile, CREATE));
    System.out.println(randomWords1);
    System.out.println(randomWords2);
    outputStream.flush();
    for (int i = 0; i < randomWords1.size(); i++) {
        outputStream.write(randomWords1.get(i).getBytes());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < randomWords2.size(); i++) {
        outputStream.write(randomWords2.get(i).getBytes());
    }
    outputStream.close();
}

private static ArrayList<String> randomFromFile(String fileName, int count) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        words.add(scanner.next());
    }
    return randomFromWords(words, count);
}

static private ArrayList<String> randomFromWords(ArrayList<String> words, int count) {
    ArrayList<String> randomWords = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ) {
        int random = new Random().nextInt(words.size());
        if (randomWords.add(words.get(random))) {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return randomWords;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.CREATE;

public class RandomWordGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path outputFile = Paths.get("output.txt");
        ArrayList<String> randomWords1 = randomWordsFromFile("input1.txt", 10);
        ArrayList<String> randomWords2 = randomWordsFromFile("input2.txt", 10);
        OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(outputFile, CREATE));
        System.out.println(randomWords1);
        System.out.println(randomWords2);
        outputStream.flush();
        for (int i = 0; i < randomWords1.size(); i++) {
            outputStream.write(randomWords1.get(i).getBytes());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < randomWords2.size(); i++) {
            outputStream.write(randomWords2.get(i).getBytes());
        }
        outputStream.close();
    }

    private static ArrayList<String> randomWordsFromFile(String fileName, int count) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            words.add(scanner.next());
        }
        return randomFromWords(words, count);
    }

    static private ArrayList<String> randomFromWords(ArrayList<String>     words, int count) {
        ArrayList<String> randomWords = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ) {
            int random = new Random().nextInt(words.size());
            if (randomWords.add(words.get(random))) {
                i++;
            }
        }
        return randomWords;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is this instead of the code that I have included above?

Comment: above code was not giving random strings and not giving exact number of count. the code i post will do both

Comment: How would I serialise the two lists in a binary file? Because although the program above picks 10 words at random and prints them out, it doesn't actually store the words does it?

Comment: no. but you can use OutputStreamWriter to write to file. take one one one from list and write to file. now your list have string element which is already serialised. if you have your custom object then you need to serialize it.

Comment: I've tried to implement the OutputStreamWriter to my program but I don't think I've done it correctly. Could you advise how I would go about serialising the lists in a binary file? (See my attempt in the question above).

Comment: Added solution here ( https://github.com/gopinath-langote/solutions/tree/master/src/randomwords )

Comment: Your help is greatly appreciated, however, since I have two text files as the input file, would the edit's above be correct?

Comment: Yes. Which is absolutely fine and working. [updated my repo on GitHub](https://github.com/gopinath-langote/solutions/tree/master/src/randomwords). Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your help! So I'm correct in thinking that this program successfully serialises the array of 2 lists in a binary file?

Comment: Yes. I tried it on my machine. working fine. You can check if it running and satisfying all you criteria. If not let's discuss to solve problem.

Answer (score 1):

Generate 10 random numbers using `Math.random()` and times them by the size of your array of the numbers (as they are a value between 0 and 1) and use these numbers to select items from your array. For example try looping this 10 times: `Array[Math.random()*sizeOfArray]`

Comment: This may sometimes pick the same word more than once. Don’t know if that would be OK. Fixes include: (1) try again if you got a word that had already been picked once (2) shuffle the list and then take the 10 first entries.

Comment: You can also pick the element by removing it from the list: String newPick = arrayList.remove(Math.random()*arrayList.size()); So it won't be picked again.

Comment: shuffle the list and then pick the first 10 elements of it